# Possible to select whether group contains an element (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given:

```
col1  col2
0    'a'
0    'b'
1    'a'
1    'b'
1    'c'
2    'b'
2    'c'
```

I'd like to select the columns:

```
col1  col2  col2_has_a_or_b_in_group
0    'a'    True
0    'b'    True
1    'a'    True
1    'b'    True
1    'c'    True
2    'c'    False  -- no a or b in group 2   
2    'd'    False
```

where the new column, `col2_has_a_or_b_in_group`, if True is `col2` contains 'a' or 'b' if in the same group as `col1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below!

```
SELECT 
A.*, 
CASE WHEN has_a_and_b IS NULL THEN False ELSE has_a_and_b END AS has_a_and_b
FROM table_1 A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    True AS has_a_and_b,
    col1,
    col2,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) AS count_if_a_and_b 
    FROM table_1 
    WHERE col2 IN ('a', 'b') 
) B
ON A.col1 = B.col1 AND A.col2 = B.col2
WHERE B.count_if_a_and_b = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative using arrays, since I love them so much:

```
with possibilities as (
  select col1, array_agg (distinct col2) as col2
  from table
  group by col1
)
select
  t.col1, t.col2,
  p.col2 && array['a', 'b']
from
  table t
  join possibilities p on t.col1 = p.col1
```

That said, it's going to be wildly inefficient for large datasets.  The efficient but not fun version would look like this:

```
with possibilities as (
  select distinct col1
  from table
  where col2 in ('a', 'b')
)
select
  t.col1, t.col2, p.col1 is not null
from
  table t
  Left join possibilities p on t.col1 = p.col1
```